# Cannot execute count query in JDBC Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, mapreduce, hive

I am using HiveServer2. I am trying to use the JDBC from cwiki.apache.org. Everything runs well in the code except for this query (the connection was successful and I was able to create a table and load data into it):

```
sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getString(1));
}
```

I checked the hive log files and found the following 2 errors:

> ERROR mr.ExecDriver (MapRedTask.java:execute(304)) - Exception: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/hadoop-2.2.0\bin\hadoop.cmd" (in directory "C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin\hive-0.12.0-bin\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(419)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Comment: Are you sure that the files mapped to the table are not deleted from HDFS?

Comment: Yes for sure because a simple SELECT query is working

Comment: Thanks!!can you check if the same command is  running from hive command line? Then it would be some issue with the one of the configuration XML's

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a problem in the command line. When I write any query, nothing happens. The only way to work in my command line is to write ./hive -e 'SHOW TABLES' (for example).

Comment: it would really help to solve this if you can tell  **./hive -e 'select count(1) from yourtable'** runs sucessfully. I know too many questions from my side... but cant help :)

Comment: Consider ./hive -e 'select count(1) from mytable' runs sucessfully. How Can we solve my issue?

Comment: I tried it from commant line, same error :/

Comment: I solved it from command line, I exported HADOOP_HOME. But the problem persists when running the jdbc @grepcode